# TIBCO Spotfire cannot open information link (empty password (HRESULT: 80131509))

Tags: sql-server, spotfire

I've installed Spotfire server 6.0.1 and Spotfire professional (same version).
I've also installed the demo data provided by the package. 
Everything works fine but I cannot open the information links provided e.g. in
(Demo -> Information Model -> Database Marketing -> Store)
I get this message:

```
Error message: Could not open information link.

ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to open information link. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.ConnectWithoutPrompting
(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, 
Boolean updateInternalState)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.Connect(IServiceProvider 
serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean 
updateInternalState) 
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSource
(InformationLinkDataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings 
documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.
OpenDataSource(DataSource dataSource, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.
DoOperationLoop()

InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
An Internal Error has occurred. Illegal configuration: empty password 
(HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
at    Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.
GetJobSpecForId(Guid informationLinkId)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSource.GetJobSpec()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSource.ConnectCore
(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.ConnectWithoutPrompting(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean updateInternalState)

InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services:
An Internal Error has occurred. Illegal configuration: empty password 
(HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.WebServiceBase`1.InvokeService[T]
(ServiceMethod`1 serviceMethod, ExceptionFactoryMethod exceptionFactoryMethod)
at    Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.
GetJobSpecForId(Guid informationLinkId)
```

Please note that every other operations and connections are working just fine.
I just cannot access information links.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the password for the "Demo Data" data source (and also update the connection URL if you haven't done so).

1. Open the Information Designer (available under "Tools" if you have the right licenses)
2. Select the "Demo Data" data source in the "Data Sources" tab
3. Right-click and select "Edit..."
4. Enter the password you selected when you ran the database creation scripts and update the connection URL
5. Save your changes and you should be good to go!